# Function produces different output after coverting it to a generator function

Tags: python, generator, yield-return

I created the following algorithm to create a function for the generation of the [Baum-Sweet-Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Sweet_sequence).

```
def baum_sweettest(number_as_byte):
    counter = 0
    for bit in str(number_as_byte):
      print("bit = ", bit)
      if bit == "0":
        counter += 1 
      if bit == "1":
        if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
          counter = 0
          return 0
    print("counter = ", counter)
    if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
      counter = 0
      return 0
    else:
      return 1

print(baum_sweettest(110))
```

I am fairly new to Python so I am aware that this is probably far from the best way to solve it. Any feedback on this is welcome, however I am primarily interested in why this function creates different results, when converted to the following generator-function:

```
def baum_sweet():
    yield 1
    counter = 0
    for n in range(1,1000):
        number_as_binary = bin(n)[2::]
        for bit in str(number_as_binary):
            if bit == "0": 
                counter += 1 
            if bit == "1":
                if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
                    counter = 0
                    yield 0
        if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
            counter = 0
            yield 0
        else:
            counter = 0
            yield 1
```

`baum_sweettest()` returns 0 when tested for the number 6 (110) which is correct.

The generator-object created by `baum_sweet` delivers/yields correct results up to the number 6, where it yields 1.

Since the algorithm is the same in both cases I guess this is due to a different behavior in generator functions. Reading through the documentation I found, that those are not terminated, but rather just continued until the next yield-statement. So I made sure that my counter will be reset manually before every yield. However the generator-version of my algorithm still yields different results at some point, as the same algorithm in a "non-generator-function".

Can someone elaborate why those two functions return/yield different results?

Comment: Can you fix your second code indentation ?

Comment: `yield` doesn't exit the function. Your generator function can emit multiple values for one value of `n`.

Comment: as @khelwood said, `yield` does not exit the generator, it yields the new value. You can explicitly return from a generator by just calling `return`. If there are no `yield` calls then its not a generator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here's how I would convert the function into a generator — basically just by replacing the `return`s with `yield` statemtnts:

```
def baum_sweettest(number_as_byte):
    counter = 0
    for bit in str(number_as_byte):
      print("bit = ", bit)
      if bit == "0":
        counter += 1
      if bit == "1":
        if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
          counter = 0
          return 0
    print("counter = ", counter)
    if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
      counter = 0
      return 0
    else:
      return 1

print(baum_sweettest(110))

# Generator version.
def baum_sweet(number_as_byte):
    counter = 0
    for bit in str(number_as_byte):
      print("bit = ", bit)
      if bit == "0":
        counter += 1
      if bit == "1":
        if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
          counter = 0
          yield 0
    print("counter = ", counter)
    if counter%2 !=0 or counter == 1:
      counter = 0
      yield 0
    else:
      yield 1

print()
for counter in baum_sweet(110):
    pass
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
bit =  1
bit =  1
bit =  0
counter =  1
0

bit =  1
bit =  1
bit =  0
counter =  1
0
```